# @ngtools/webpack error while loading linked npm package - "Consider changing the function expression into an exported function."

Tags: angular, webpack, aot

I am having issues compiling a linked npm package to run it with the dev-server (I have an extracted webpack config from CLI). The issue occurs since my update to angular 5.

Thank you in advance!

#### Error

Always this error occurs when trying to compile the package, no files are being generated either:

```
ERROR in my-package/src/app/my.module.ts(198,2): Error during template compile of 'MyModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'NgModule'
    'NgModule' contains the error at @angular/core/core.ts(194,31)
      Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

#### Versions

```
node v8.2.1
npm v5.5.1
Mac OSX High Sierra

angular v5.1.1
@ngtools/webpack v1.9.2
webpack v3.10.0
typescript v2.5.3
```

#### How to reproduce

- Do a fresh npm install
- Link the package in the current project
- run the dev build/start the dev server (no production plugins used)

#### webpack configuration

```
{
       //...
       module: {
            rules: [
               {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    use: [ '@ngtools/webpack' ]
                },
             ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
               mainPath: "src/main.ts",
               sourceMap: true,
               tsConfigPath: "tsconfig.aot.json",
               entryModule: "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
            }), // ...
         ]
}
// ...
```

#### Angular modules

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        // ....
        MyModule.forRoot()
    ],
    // ...
})
export class AppModule {
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        // ...
    ],
    declarations: [
         // ...
    ],
    exports: [
         // ...
    ]

})
export class MyModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: MyModule,
            providers: [
                // ...
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Compiling the package with the installed version of the package is working fine and produces output files.

#### tsconfig files

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.aot.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.js",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.mock.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: show your providers?

Comment: Which providers do you mean? There are just normal angular services in my application.

Comment: if you have any function calls in your providers array, that could explain it

Comment: Ah OK, that is what you meant. But no unfortunately there is no function call in it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the exact same problem except where yours says "'NgModule' contains the error at @angular/core/core.ts(194,31)" mine says "'NgModule' calls a function at @angular/core/core.ts(194,50)". But otherwise the same. Can't figure it out.

Comment: No I did not figure it out. In fact my solution was to use @ngtools/webpack plugin for AOT builds and default awesome-typescript-loader etc. for running it locally without AOT.